# How to Put the Back Button in Left of my ActionBar

Tags: android, xml, android-layout, android-activity

I'm building and finishing a Android App and this is one of the main things I need to Fix it up.

So, I have a Action Bar styled like this:

```
<resources>
    <style name="MyCustomTheme" parent="@android:style/Theme.Holo.Light">
        <item name="android:actionBarStyle">@style/MyActionBarTheme</item>
    </style>

    <style name="MyActionBarTheme" parent="@android:style/Widget.Holo.Light.ActionBar">
        <item name="android:background">#F6E6E7</item>
        <item name="android:textSize">10sp</item>
    </style>

    <style name="CustomTabWidget">
        <item name="android:textSize">15sp</item>
    </style>


</resources>
```

And this is the layout where i put the button

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >
    <!-- Search, should appear as action button -->

    <item android:id="@+id/voltar"
        android:title="Voltar"
        android:icon="@drawable/abc_ic_ab_back_holo_light"
        android:showAsAction="ifRoom" />
    <!-- Settings, should always be in the overflow -->

</menu>
```

this Button Tittled Voltar is at the Right Side of the Action Bar.. What Should I Do to put this on Left Side?

Thank you for read this

Comment: I think options menu is not the best way for implementing your back button. Do you want the back button to navigate to the parent activity?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to do two things. First declare this in the `onCreate` of your activity

```
getActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
```

Then implement the `onOptionsItemSelected` so that it handles the home as up button click event

```
@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    if (item.getItemId() == android.R.id.home ) {
        finish();
        return true;
    }
    // other menu select events may be present here

    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}
```

Comment: If you using AppCompatCtivity instead of android.app.Activity you need to use getSupportActionBar()

Answer (score 5):

Declaring `getActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);` in the onCreate of your activity is right.

However, onOptionsItemSelected implementation suggested by Nayan in the post above can be improved and should be handled as per code below:

```
@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    int id = item.getItemId();
    if (id == android.R.id.home) {
        NavUtils.navigateUpFromSameTask(this);
//            finish();
        return true;
    }
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}
```

The id android.R.id.home represents the Home or Up button. Declaring `getActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);` will cause the UP (Back/Left Arrow) button to be show. Use NavUtils to allow users to navigate up one level in the application structure.

For more details, see the Navigation pattern on Android Design:
http://developer.android.com/design/patterns/navigation.html#up-vs-back

Answer (score 1):

Back Button is supported in android by default.
You don't need to create the button manually.
Just in the Activity's `onCreate()` method

```
getActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
```

Comment: Ok. I'm almost in love with you right now. Thank you!